# Predix indoor positioning api - GE system

Tags: indoor-positioning-system, predix

Does anyone have any experience with the Predix [indoor positioning API](https://www.predix.io/services/service.html?id=1768) and actual devices ? I'm interested in the reliability of the positioning and how much of a burden the client app is on a phone.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used that particular service, but I've used many of the other Predix services.  This is just a REST API that returns historical data.  I don't think that service returns live location data.  So, it would depend on how much data you request in your API call.  It's just like any other REST call... if you request a million data points, it would probably be too much for your mobile app.  But if you request a small data set, there would be no problem.